# How to change background color in excel on word cell value?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2007

I want the cell to turn green when I type in "win" or red when I type in "lost".
How do I do that?

I tried with Conditional formatting but I was only able to do it for one word value. There was no "if" win then green or "if" lost then red.

Thanks! Tine

Answer (score 3):

You can set several rules for Conditional Formatting within the same set of cells. Just create another condition, as you did for the "win" one :

- If "win" => green
- If "lost" => red

The format of the first hit rule will be applied to your cell.